# The method is undefined for the type T

Tags: java, generics, undefined, undefined-function

I am trying this example, but can't make it work; it throws `The method getFromInt(int) is undefined for the type T`

`T` is a generic enum type

```
public static <T> T deserializeEnumeration(InputStream inputStream) {
        int asInt = deserializeInt(inputStream);
        T deserializeObject = T.getFromInt(asInt);
        return deserializeObject;
    }
```

am calling the previous method as follows for example:

```
objectToDeserialize.setUnit(InputStreamUtil.<Unit>deserializeEnumeration(inputStream));
```

or

```
objectToDeserialize.setShuntCompensatorType(InputStreamUtil.<ShuntCompensatorType>deserializeEnumeration(inputStream));
```

or etc...

Comment: What should `T` be?

Comment: @Lino it should be generic enum type

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: T in your code is an extend of java.lang.Object and getFromInt is not define for object

Comment: @Wernerson I have some enums which all have getFromInt method, I want to use one generic object inside a generic method to pass a value to getFromInt regardless the type of the object.

Comment: I don't believe this is required to be generic for an enum. Enum is a type that can't be extended so it will ALWAYS be the same type. `public static MyEnum deserializeEnumeration(InputStream inputStream)` Now if you want more than one enum to be returned, you will need to pass the type as a parameter `public static <T> T deserializeEnumeration(InputStream inputStream, Class<T> type)` but again, `T` is just an `Object` so the method won't exist. You need a common type that declare `getFromInt` but I don't believe an `enum` can implement an interface, it can't extends a class for sur...

Comment: @AxelH `enum`s can implement interfaces

Comment: I wasn't sure about it @Lino, I suspect it, thanks

Comment: I edited my post and added more details I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack your way around this. As you've stated in the comments:

> *I have some enums which all have getFromInt method*

With a slight adaptation to the method, by adding a new parameter, the type of the enum, you can use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) to invoke said `getFromInt` method:

```
public static <T> T deserializeEnumeration(Class<? extends T> type, InputStream inputStream){
    try {
        int asInt = deserializeInt(inputStream);
        // int.class indicates the parameter
        Method method = type.getDeclaredMethod("getAsInt", int.class);
        // null means no instance as it is a static method
        return method.invoke(null, asInt);
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException e){
       throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am calling `deserializeEnumeration` for example 
`objectToDeserialize.setUnit(InputStreamUtil.<Unit>deserializeEnumeration(inputStream));`
how to modifieded it in order to adapt your code?

Comment: @SalemMasoud try `objectToDeserialize.setUnit(InputStreamUtil.deserializeEnumeration(Unit.class, inputStream));`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just **converting** from `int` to a new type `T`, why don't you just try to pass in a `lambda` [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) to do the conversion as follows:

```
public class FunctionInterface {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        getT(1, String::valueOf);
    }

    private static <T> T getT(int i, Function<Integer, T> converter) {
        return converter.apply(i); // passing in the function;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You haven't specified that `T` has a method `getFromInt(int)`.
2. You are trying to call a `static` method from a generic parameter - this will not work.

Something like this should work:

```
interface FromInt {
    FromInt getFromInt(int i);
}

enum MyEnum implements FromInt {
    Hello,
    Bye;

    @Override
    public FromInt getFromInt(int i) {
        return MyEnum.values()[i];
    }
}

public static <T extends Enum<T> & FromInt> T deserializeEnumeration(Class<T> clazz, InputStream inputStream) {
    int asInt = 1;
    // Use the first element of the `enum` to do the lookup.
    FromInt fromInt = clazz.getEnumConstants()[0].getFromInt(asInt);
    return (T)fromInt;
}
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote, if `getFromInt` always does an index lookup, then `clazz.getEnumConstans()[asInt]` may even be used and the method `getFromInt` can be thrown into the trash